# Better way to replace unnecessary scan.nextLine(); to find StdIn String?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, stdin

I've been working through the HackerRank problems and trying to always research a solution before asking in any communities for help. While I managed to get the current one to work, I feel there is some unnecessary code involved and that someone can teach me how to do it better, as I'd hate to pick up a bad habit just because it works.

In this lesson HackRank 30 days of Code (Day 2), we were asked to read 3 lines (an Int, a Double and a String) from Stdin and use the Scanner to read them, save them and manipulate them.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    /* Declare second integer, double, and String variables. */
    int myI = scan.nextInt();
    double myDouble = scan.nextDouble();
    scan.nextLine();
    String myString = scan.nextLine();
```

Scanning for the Int and Double was easy enough, but when I tried to scan for the  String I ran into some issue:

A) If I used scan.next(); I got back one word instead of the full string.

B) If I used scan.nextLine(); I got back a blank line.

After some research I found someone suggesting that because I just did a scan.nextDouble(); the scan.nextLine(); was simply reading the blanks at the end of that line (which didn't make much sense to me), and that if I added in an extra "scan.nextLine();" before declaring my string it should work.

Sure enough it did. I don't really understand why, and it certainly doesn't feel like this is the right way to solve this. It seems that if I had to do that frequently it would just bloat the code?

Can anyone shed some light on:

1) Why scan.nextLine(); was returning blank until I added an extra one?

2) Is there a better way to locate the string from the scan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scan.nextLine() returns everything up until the next new line delimiter, or \n.

So, i'm assuming the input look something like this:

```
1 2.5
whatever
```

So, this string actually has a next line delimiter between the first line and the second line. Before, when you didn't have that extra nextLine(), your string was being assigned to an empty string, since it was consuming the next line delimiter.

The extra nextLine() was consuming the unwanted next line delimeter, so your string could be assigned to what you wanted it to be.

Comment: That helps wrap my head around the issue, by using the nextDouble I was only picking out the double not its entire line!

Is there a more eloquent solution to this though?

Comment: @AdamS.Cochran As far as i know, not really. This is the method I use for now. Also, remember to mark this as correct if this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

To write the code in fewer lines, you can read the newline character and parse myDouble in the same line.

```
    int myI = scan.nextInt();
    double myDouble = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
    String myString = scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: While that is less lines it's really the same number of things being done, so I can't imagine it's less process intensive, but certainly better format. I guess I was more asking if there is a way to do it without needing the extra "nextLine" at all.

Answer (score 0):

scan.nextLine();
Why is this there? I think thats why its messing it up.
Also how I have learned to do it is like this.

```
    System.out.println("Enter String");
    String string = read.nextLine();
```

Comment: The code snippet above is working as-is. I just wanted to know if there is a better way to do it. Also your method works if there is only one input, in this test case we are being passed 3 inputs at the same time an Int, Double and String.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that if you use the `nextLine()` method immediately following the `nextInt()` method will read *blank*/*empty*. This is because `nextInt()` reads integer tokens, hence the last *newline* character for that line (integer input) is still queued in the input buffer.
This eventually tricks the next `nextLine()`, finally it will be reading the remainder of the integer line, which is empty.

So to my knowledge for Stdin, if you had to accept the string input after accepting the integer/double/float then you have to use the dummy `nextLine()`; to trick the output.

Answer (score 0):

Simple bro use scan.next() only

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet will help:

```
    int i = scan.nextInt();
    double d = scan.nextDouble();
    scan.nextLine();
    String s = scan.nextLine();`
```